# Using multiprocessing to in a function with multiple return in simulation

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, return

I want to run simulations with different random seeds at the same time. The sequential code to run the simulations is:

```
def run_multiple_simulations(n=10,T=T,p=p):
    A,B,C,D,E=[],[],[],[],[]
    for i in range(n):
        a,b,c,d,e= do_simulation(T,p=p,seed=i)
        A.append([a])
        B.append([b])
        C.append([c])
        D.append([d])
        E.append([e])
    return A,B,C,D,E
```

Is there a way to get the results as in the return statement of `run_multiple_simulations()` (a,b,c,d and e are arrays).

Comment: Please add a minimum runnable code and your expected results.

Comment: Yep, it's possible imo. Checkout joblib or multiprocessing module but to help you, we will need a minimal code sample to reproduce the behaviour! Write a snipped for just one simulation, give it an id value and put that in multi-processing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def do_simulation(t, p, seed):  # (1)
    return (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

def run_multiple_simulations(n, t, p):
    def _do_simulation(seed):  # (2)
        return do_simulation(t, p, seed)

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as e:
        results = e.map(_do_simulation, range(n))  # (3)

    return tuple(zip(*results))  # (4)

print(run_multiple_simulations(3, 0, 0))
```

I defined a mocked up version of your function in (1). The function (2) is a curried version of (1) with just the seed parameter as it is the only parameter that changes between executions. Then, a `ThreadPoolExecutor` is used to do the work in parallel (3). Finally (4), the results is formated like you want (a tuple of lists).